# Finding an element in $l_1$ space with certain properties

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I am facing a bit problem in the following: Given $x_1,...,x_m \in l^\infty$ and positive $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_m$, I need to find an element $a= (a_n)$ in $l_1$ space such that $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty |a_n|=1$ and $|\sum_{n=1}^ \infty a_n x_{n,k}|< \epsilon_k$ for all $1 \leq k \leq m$, where $x_k =(x_{n,k})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Fact**: If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space and $F\subset X^*$ is a finite-dimensional subspace, (where $X^*$ denotes the dual space of $X$) then the set

$$\{x\in X: x^*(x)=0 \, \forall x^*\in F\}$$

is an infinite-dimensional subspace of $X$. In particular, it contains a unit vector.

Now in your case, you have $m$ elements of $(l_1)^*=l^{\infty}$, which span at most an $m$-dimensional subspace of $l^{\infty}$, and so invoking the fact you can find $a\in l_1$ such that $||a||_1=1$ and 
$$x_k^*(a)=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx_{n,k}\right|=0<\varepsilon_k$$
for each $k=1,2,\dots,m$

Comment: I am looking for a direct proof without the use of any result. Moreover, I got this question in a topology book and not in functional analysis. Thank you.